Man looking for treasure, only to be strangled by a skeletal hand
This is an English horror movie I watched on television in 1990s. One of the scene is as follows:

A man is looking for some treasure in some house. … He digs (or opens some compartment in) the ground, instead finding a skeleton whose right hand is missing. … In place of the skeleton's missing hand, there is a letter (or plaque) with hint about the treasure's real location. … He decides the treasure is behind some large painting. … He opens the compartment behind the painting, finding out the skeleton's missing hand who strangles him to death.


I know this isn't it, but talking about paintings, skeletons, and burried treasure reminds me of The Goonies.

Is it one of the House films? I recall some sections regarding a disembodied skeletal hand. The rest of the plot points don't seem to tie up though...

Twice-Told Tales (1963)  Final story  "House of the Seven Gables"
From Wkipedia:

Gerald Pyncheon (Price) returns to his family house after an absence
  of 17 years, bringing with him his wife Alice. His sister Hannah, who
  had been living in the house, tells Alice about the curse put upon
  Pyncheon men by Matthew Maulle, who used to own the house but lost it
  in a shady deal to the Pyncheon family. Jonathan Maulle, a descendant
  of Matthew, arrives, but he refuses Gerald's offer to give him the
  house in exchange for the location of a vault where valuable property
  deeds are stored. Alice becomes haunted by the curse on the house,
  which eventually leads her to the cellar.
Gerald finds her there and discovers the map to the vault. He kills
  Hannah to keep her share of the inheritance. Gerald traps Alice in the
  basement grave of Mathew Maulle, then goes to the study to find the
  vault. He opens it, and a skeletal hand inside the vault kills him.
  Jonathan arrives and takes Alice out of the house, just as it shakes
  and collapses.

Final Scene
